# check if a city is in a country with northeast lat/lng and southwest lat/lng

Tags: php, json, google-maps, geometry

I'm working on a PHP application which uses google API's, and i would like to check if a city is in a country.

for example : is Paris in France ?

**France** geometry bounds :

```
 "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.089166,
                  "lng" : 9.560067799999999
               },
 "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 41.3423276,
                  "lng" : -5.141227900000001
               }
```

**Paris** geometry bounds :

```
 "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 48.9021449,
              "lng" : 2.4699208
           },
 "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 48.815573,
              "lng" : 2.224199
           }
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you getting those bounds? If you are using the geocoding servce (or the places library), there is usually additional information about what country it belongs to.

Comment: Yes i know, but i can't check with the geocoding service if an adress_sreet belongs or not to a neighborhood

Comment: Your question was about cities in countries, not addresses in neighborhoods.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Check this out I made an example:

```
function inRange($value, $max, $min) {
   return $value >= $min && $value <= $max;
}

$city_coords_northeast = // put your northeast city coords here(array)
$city_coords_southwest = // put your southwest city coords here(array)

$country_coords_northeast = // put your northeast country coords here(array)
$country_coords_southwest = // put your southwest country coords here(array)

if( inRange($city_coords_northeast['lat'], $country_coords_northeast['lat'], $country_coords_southwest['lat']) && 
    inRange($city_coords_northeast['long'], $country_coords_northeast['long'], $country_coords_southwest['long']) &&
    inRange($country_coords_southwest['lat'], $city_coords_northeast['lat'], $city_coords_southwest['lat']) &&
    inRange($country_coords_southwest['long'], $city_coords_northeast['long'], $city_coords_southwest['long']) ) {
   echo 'Paris is in France!';
}
```

PS: I don't think this is very fast, but it makes its job.

Comment: you mean "function inRange($value, $max, $min)" and you have forget to replace country_coords_southwest by city_coords_southwest in the 3rd and 4th ling of inrange

Comment: in the 3rd and 4th line, you reverse city and country, we compare a city coord to a range of country. But in this solution we are comparing two square and not two circles, so this can't work with another coords.

Comment: we have to check if a circle is inside another circle and not a square in another square you see ?

Comment: Yep, this is a bit confusing and hard to understand i don't know what should i do...